# Finding a Substring in A Link

Tags: python, string, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So in my Python function, I pass on a url, search for pdf files on that url and then download those files. For most cases, it works perfectly.

```
def get_pdfs(my_url):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(my_url).read()
    html_page = BeautifulSoup(html)
    current_link = ''
    links = []
    for link in html_page.find_all('a'):
        current_link = link.get('href')
        if current_link.endswith('pdf'):
            print(current_link)
            links.append(my_url + current_link)
    #print(links)

    for link in links:
        #urlretrieve(link)
        wget.download(link)


get_pdfs('https://grader.eecs.jacobs-university.de/courses/320241/2019_2/')
```

However when I try using my function for a particular course website, my `current_link` is

```
/courses/320241/2019_2/lectures/lecture_7_8.pdf
```

though it should be automatically detected & should be only

```
lectures/lecture_7_8.pdf
```

while the original my_url that I passed on to the function was

```
https://grader.eecs.jacobs-university.de/courses/320241/2019_2/
```

since I'm appending both of them & a part of the link is repeated, the files downloaded are corrupted. How can I check `current_link` if any part is repeated from `my_url` and if yes, how can I remove it before downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update using `urljoin` from `urllib.parse` will do job:

```
import urllib.parse import urljoin

def get_pdfs(my_url):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(my_url).read()
    html_page = BeautifulSoup(html)
    current_link = ''
    links = []
    for link in html_page.find_all('a'):
        current_link = link.get('href')
        if current_link.endswith('pdf'):
            print(current_link)
            links.append(urljoin(my_url, current_link))
    #print(links)

    for link in links:
        #urlretrieve(link)
        wget.download(link)
```

Simplified method, `.select('a[href$=pdf]')` select all links in which the href ends with pdf:

```
import urllib.parse import urljoin

def get_pdfs(my_url):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(my_url).read()
    html_page = BeautifulSoup(html)
    [wget.download(urljoin(my_url, link.get('href'))) for link in html_page.select('a[href$=pdf]')]
```

Comment: You can also evaluate what the current_link value is.  


- If your current link starts with `http://` or `https://`, it means the link points to an external server.  You could use the URL just as is.


- If your link starts with `/`, it means it is an absolute path from your current server (i.e. base_url).  You can use `f'{base_url}/{current_link}'`


- If the link starts with something else, you would need to build the relative path as: `f'{base_url}/{course_path}/{current_link}'`

Comment: @Byob I'm actually trying to make a function where the user just has to enter the link, not the course path. I need a way that I can search in ```my_url`` and see if a part of the string is matching with the ```current_link```. If it is, I want to remove the matching part and concatenate the rest to open the link.

Comment: For instance, if I download ```https://grader.eecs.jacobs-university.de/courses/320241/2019_2/lectures/lecture_7_8.pdf``` using wget, it works perfectly. So I need some kind of string parsing technique

Comment: It's html is like this: ```<tr>
<td>2019-09-26, 27</td>
<td><a href="/courses/320241/2019_2/lectures/lecture_7_8.pdf">Lecture 7, 8</a></td>
</tr>```

Comment: @x89 Check the answer update. Using urllib.parse you can urljoin that will all job for you.